# Higher fuel usage over 3 years

Tags: vw, fuel-consumption, tdi

I have noticed a higher fuel usage over the time I have owned my 1.6TDI vw diesel. Some of it has to do with the way I drive the car (somewhat more spirited) but some must be caused by a different issue. I have gone from about 4.5L/100kms on average to about 5.5-6L/100.
I have been told to check my fuel injectors. Is there a way to test those? Could there be another issue? Using same tires, car weight is the same, there were no tunes made, no car body changes etc.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Another thing to consider is if you've changed where you fuel at. Different fuel can provide different results.

Comment: there are not that many different pumps around these parts and I've always used 2-3. I haven't noticed any difference between them back then and no difference now, just different from back then and now.

Comment: I was actually referring to different fueling stations, not different grades of diesel. Different brands of diesel can give different results in mileage. If you changed brands at some point, it could be a reason why mileage has decreased. Fuel filters and injectors can affect mileage as you've already surmised. If these haven't been cleaned or replaced on schedule, it's maintenance you probably want to perform before you deep dive your issues.

Comment: Add air filter to my above list. If you can't draw air like it should, then your mileage can suffer.

Comment: How are you measuring the fuel consumption – from the gauge, or by the distance from full-to-full and the volume sold? I once refuelled at a garage away from home, more than I had ever put in it, and more than the tank was rated to hold. The pump you use might be out of calibration, or you might be being cheated.

Comment: Check your O2 sensors. They influence fueling a lot. A failed O2 will change the fuel mixture significantly. And, always keep your servicing up. Diesels are unforgiving of neglect. My 1.9TDI Golf would drop off in economic performance if it needed a service (oil change, mainly)

Comment: Is your TDI pre or post VWs Dieselgate? Does it use DEF with SCR?

Comment: It is 2014 1.6 TDI 77kw, from what I've seen, it was not affected by dieselgate. It has no SCR either.